# Endless recyclerview stackFromEnd type like Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, chat

I need to implement a simple chat client on Android and in this application there is a `stackFromEnd` in my `RecyclerView` which I need to populate its data from database (or my server). So I added `OnScrollListener` to my list as below.

```
messageList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if (messageLoading == false && layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
            messageLoading = true;
            ActionManager.getInstance().getChatAction().getThreadMessages(thread);
        }

        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    }
});
```

The problem is when its called, the `RecyclerView` jumps to the first item of the list.

P.S:

```
ActionManager.getInstance().getChatAction().getThreadMessages(thread)
```

Just adds new items to adapter and calls `notifyDataSetChanged`

P.S.S:

Is there any library for message list (e.g. whatsapp, messenger etc.?!)

Comment: remove `super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);` this line

Comment: @ShaishavJogani not working of course! It's just an empty function

Comment: @strings95 are you able to find any solution for this? Thanks.